# Reasons to have a dedicated logout page

Tags: php, theory

In user-based websites, it is very common for websites to use a page like "logout.php", and I even use them myself on my own projects, but now I am wondering why. So my question is: Are there any specific advantages to using a dedicated file for logging out users? Would it not be more organized to just create a method within any appropriate class, such as:

Here is an example written in PHP (this is similar to what I have started to use):

```
public class Admin {

   private function logout() {
        $_SESSION[ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY] = null;
        unset($_SESSION[ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY]);
        return ($_SESSION[ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY]) ? false : true;    
   } 

}
```

This function would then be triggered by some $_POST or $_GET variable, or any other way of doing it.

My only guess about why it is so popular (google, facebook, etc. do this last I checked) to use single dedicated file for the logout process it that you can simply direct the user to the page (logout.php) and they will be logged out no matter what, provided that the page loads and executes properly. Can you think of any good advantages for either method?

Comment: The `PHP frameworks` use `method` for logging out user.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Which framework(s)?

Comment: Probably all of them, the point is - you will write this methods and store wherever you want to, just to describe better, "website.com/logout" here is logout is a method of controller like "user" with set routing to him, check what is MVC, and to start i recommend CodeIgniter framework, he is friendly for new coders

Comment: @deraad I used `Yii, Cakephp, and Codeigniter`. All using `methods`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily its own file. In most cases the site is running an MVC where url parameters are parsed into class methods. So though you are visiting `host.com/account/logout` - you are just simply calling the `logout()` method in the `account` class (in its simplest form) in the easiest way possible from the browser.

You'd think this could be done with JavaScript by simply deleting the cookies on the client side, but best practice is to destroy the server stored session also, so it can't be recovered by anyone (like an attacker)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage i can think of is that it allows developers to keep `<a href="logout.php">logout</a>` type logout button, which are not dependent on jquery or any other client-side javascript to log you out. You just redirect/link them to another page, which takes care of removing their session data.

Its just a plain, and simple URL. Sometimes people even prefer typing it in the URL, i know i do!